# set x/y limits in facet_wrap with scales = 'free'

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I've seen similar questions asked, and this discussion about adding functionality to **ggplot** [Setting x/y lim in facet_grid](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/cDzL_yHew0I) . In my research I often want to produce several panels plots, say for different simulation trials, where the axes limits remain the same to highlight differences between the trials. This is especially useful when showing the plot panels in a presentation. In each panel plot I produce, the individual plots require independent y axes as they're often weather variables, temperature, relative humidity, windspeed, etc. Using

```
    ggplot() + ... + facet_wrap(~ ..., scales = 'free_y')
```

works great as I can easily produce plot panels of different weather variables.
[image: example weather variable plot panel] When I compare between different plot panels, its nice to have consistent axes. Unfortunately **ggplot** provides no way of setting the individual limits of each plot within a panel plots. It defaults to using the range of given data. The Google Group discussion linked above discusses this shortcoming, but I was unable to find any updates as to whether this could be added. Is there a way to trick **ggplot** to set the individual limits?

Answer (score 7):

A first suggestion that somewhat sidesteps the solution I'm looking for is to combine all my data into one data table and use **facet_grid** on my variable and simulation

```
    ggplot() + ... + facet_grid(variable~simulation, scales = 'free_y')
```

This produces a fine looking plot that displays the data in one figure, but can become unwieldy when considering many simulations.
[image: facet_grid solution]

To 'hack' the plotting into producing what I want, I first determined which limits I desired for each weather variable. These limits were found by looking at the greatest extents for all simulations of interest. Once determined I created a small data table with the same columns as my simulation data and appended it to the end. My simulation data had the structure

```
    'year' 'month' 'variable' 'run' 'mean'
     1973     1     'rhmax'     1    65.44
     1973     2     'rhmax'     1    67.44
     ...     ...      ...      ...    ...
     2011    12    'windmin'   200    0.4
```

So I created a new data table with the same columns

```
    ylims.sims <- data.table(year = 1, month = 13, 
    variable =  rep(c('rhmax','rhmin','sradmean','tmax','tmin','windmax','windmin'), each = 2),
    run = 201, mean = c(20, 100, 0, 80, 100, 350, 25, 40, 12, 32, 0, 8, 0, 2))
```

Which gives

```
    'year' 'month' 'variable' 'run' 'mean'
       1     13     'rhmax'    201    20
       1     13     'rhmax'    201    100
       1     13     'rhmin'    201    0
       1     13     'rhmin'    201    80
       1     13    'sradmean'  201    100
       1     13    'sradmean'  201    350
       1     13     'tmax'     201    25
       1     13     'tmax'     201    40
       1     13     'tmin'     201    12
       1     13     'tmin'     201    32
       1     13    'windmax'   201    0
       1     13    'windmax'   201    8
       1     13    'windmin'   201    0
       1     13    'windmin'   201    2
```

While the choice of *year* and *run* is aribtrary, the choice of *month* need to be anything outside 1:12. I then appended this to my simulation data

```
    sim1data.ylims <- rbind(sim1data, ylims)
    ggplot() + geom_boxplot(data = sim1data.ylims, aes(x = factor(month), y = mean)) +
    facet_wrap(~variable, scale = 'free_y') + xlab('month') +
    xlim('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12')
```

When I plot these data with the y limits, I limit the x-axis values to those in the original data. The appended data table with y limits has *month* values of 13. As ggplot still scales axes to the entire dataset, even when the axes are limited, this gives me the y limits I desire. Important to note that if there are data values greater than the limits you specify, this will not work.

Before: Notice the differences in the y limits for each weather variable between the panels.

[image: before sims]
[image: before sims covars]

After: Now the y limits remain consistent for each weather variable between the panels. 
[image]

[image]

I hope to edit this post in the coming days and add a reproducible example for better explanation. Please comment if you've heard anything about adding this functionality to **ggplot**.

Comment: i believe if you were going to show a trend line or some sort of stat you would want to use scale_x_discrete(llmits=...). xlim is an abbreviation for coord_cartesian which is essentially just a zoom and so ggplot would calculate a stat with the appended data too. maybe someone can confirm.